# How to check if email exist before save the user

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await

I'm starting nodeJS / MongoDB and I'm trying to create a simple auth API.
I began by the SignIn function, but I have some difficulties with async functions when I check my form values.
I try to check every values before save a row in database. So I check password and email format, and my difficulties begin when I want to check if the email already exist.

Here you can see my function called when I submit my form :

```
export function signUp(req, res) {
    const { email, password, confirmPassword } = req.body || '';
    const allFields = { email, password, confirmPassword };

    let errors = {};
    Object.keys(allFields).forEach(async field => {
        const value = allFields[field];

        if (value === '') {
            errors = {...errors, [field]: 'Ce champ est requis'}
        } else {
            if (field === 'email') {
                if (!checkEmailFormat(value)) {
                    errors = {...errors, [field]: 'Le format de mail n\'est pas valide'}
                } else {
                    const { error, exist } = await checkEmailExist(value);
                    if (exist) {
                        console.log(exist);
                        console.log(error);
                        errors = {...errors, ...error};
                    }
                }
            }
            if (field === 'password' && password !== '' && password < 6) {
                errors = {...errors, [field]: 'Le mot de passe doit contenir plus de 6 caractères'}
            }
        }
    });

    console.log(errors);
    console.log(Object.keys(errors).length);
    console.log('--------------------');

    // Retour des erreurs vers le FRONT ou Save de l'user
    if (Object.keys(errors).length > 0) {
        console.log(errors);
        res.json({ errors });
    } else {
        ...Save my row in db
    }
}
```

And here my function `checkEmailExist` who check in db

```
const checkEmailExist = async (value) => {
    const { error, exist } = await User.findOne({'email': value}).exec()
        .then(user => {
            let res = {};
            if (user) {
                res = { error: { 'email': "Cet adresse email n'est pas disponible" }, exist: true };
            } else {
                res = { error: { 'email': "" }, exist: false };
            }
            return res;
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))

    return { error, exist };
}
```

My goal is to get the error returned from the `checkEmailExist` function, and send this errors to the FRONT with the others errors.
But `findOne` is an async function and the query is always pending when I check my array of errors `if (Object.keys(errors).length > 0) {`. So the user can be saved with and existing email.

How can I properly check if email exist before saving the user ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem at `Object.keys(allFields).forEach(async field`. The code inside foreach is `async` function, so it intermediately execute and the next line of code not waiting for it to end. You should make signUp `async`: `export async function signUp` and replace `forEach` with a regular loop:

```
for (const field in allFields) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution one : 
use checkEmailExist when user type the email in textfield using onchange or leaving the email field.

Solution two :
Use ES6 ASYNC/AWAIT to hold the flow until return true or false from checkEmailExist method.

REMOVE .then query... why do you need then if your are using await...

```
const checkEmailExist = async (value) => {
    const { error, exist } = await User.findOne({'email': value}).exec()
    return { error, exist };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like you're mixing a .then with an await.  i confess to not being an expert on async/await here, especially when mixed with promises, but could your checkEmailExist function look like:

```
const checkEmailExist = async (value) => {
    const user = await User.findOne({'email': value}).exec()
        .catch(err => console.log(err))

    let res = {};
    if (user) {
        res = { error: { 'email': "Cet adresse email n'est pas disponible" }, exist: true };
    } else {
        res = { error: { 'email': "" }, exist: false };
    }
    return res;
}
```

?

not sure if it makes a difference, but mixing the await and the then seems like it might give you unexpected results